# Not all contacts imported from Hotmail to Google Contacts

Tags: export, import, contacts, outlook.com, google-contacts

Helping a friend move from Hotmail to Gmail. First thing on the order of business is importing the contacts. After exporting the contacts from [outlook.live.com](http://outlook.live.com) as `contacts.csv` and importing them on [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) I got an error message saying:

> Imported 600 contacts out of 2377 found in file

[image]

**How come not all contacts were imported? How can I find out?**

---

After a long debugging session with Google's payed support, we identified it as a bug with the import confirmation pop-up, as in fact all 2,377 contacts were indeed imported

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a bug.

Answer (score 0):

After a long debugging session with Google's payed support, we identified it as a bug with the import confirmation pop-up, as in fact all 2,377 contacts were indeed imported